# How to extract all rows from a pandas dataframe given a series object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data as a dataframe:

```
Date         Category    Sales       Paid
8/12/2020    Table       1 table     Yes
8/12/2020    Chair       3chairs     Yes
13/1/2020    Cushion     8 cushions  Yes
24/5/2020    Table       3Tables     Yes
31/10/2020   Chair       12 Chairs   No
11/7/2020    Mats        12Mats      Yes
11/7/2020    Mats        4Mats       Yes
```

When I run my query I have a Series object returned that shows the Date which had the highest count of sales for the entire data.

```
ddate=df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date']).agg(sums='count').idxmax()
```

I may receive a return object that looks like this:

```
['8/12/2020']
```

In order to retrieve all rows in the original dataframe `df` I have been informed to run:

```
df[df['Date'].eq(ddate)]
```

However, this returns an empty dataframe. But if I choose a date as a string I do get back all the results

```
df[df['Date'].eq('8/12/2020')]
```

Why doesn't the series input work? How can I craft the query to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[df['Date'].eq(ddate)]` does not work because `ddate` is a `list`.

```
ddate=df['Sales'].str.extract('^(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).groupby(df['Date']).agg(sums='count').idxmax()

print(ddate)
#output
['8/12/2020']
```

In order to make it work you have to unpack the list.

Since, it is the maximum value(only one value) you can do:

```
ddate[0]
```

In equation it will be

```
df[df['Date'].eq(ddate[0])]
```

Comment: When I print the type of `ddate` the output the response I get is: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>. Why do you say it's a list?

Comment: @Dan you are right, it is pandas series.